# Acess denied on push to gitolite server

Tags: git, gitolite

All of the sudden I cannot push to origin/master on my gitolite server.

In the gitolite-admin/keydir folder I have my pub key:

```
server_user.pub
```

In the gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf file:

```
repo gitolite-admin
    RW+ = server_user
```

in the ~/.ssh folder:

```
server_user (key)
```

in the ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host    gitbox
        User gitolite
        Hostname 192.168.1.239
        Port 22
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server_user
```

I add,commit and when I try push I get the error:

```
FATAL: W any gitolite-admin server_user DENIED by fallthru
```

Git version on the server 1.7.10.4(if that is anyway relevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first the ["Emergency" page](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/emergencies/index.html):

At least, log on to the server, and run `gitolite setup -pk server_user.pub`.